# Bash function arguments not passed as expected

Tags: bash, function, arguments

I have an unexpected behaviour in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkFolders "first folder"

checkFolders() {
    checkEmptyVar $1 "folder to be copied"
}

checkEmptyVar() {
    echo "0: $0  1: $1   2: $2"
    [[ $(isNotEmpty $1) = false ]] && (echo "Specify a path for $2") && exit
    echo "post exit"
}
```

The function checkEmptyVar echoes the following:

```
0: ./lcp.sh  1: folder to be copied   2:
```

I expected to have passed "folder-to-be-copied" as `$1`of `checkEmptyVar`, what is happening?

Comment: This script isn't doing what you think it is. Your function definitions are happening too late. When you call `checkFolders` on the first line you are calling a version of that function from the pre-existing environment and not the one in that script.

Comment: You should also quote *all* your variables when you use them. Without doing that calling `checkFolders "first folder"` will then call `checkEmptyVar first folder "folder to be copied"` which isn't at all what you want.

Comment: `checkEmptyVar "$1" "folder to be copied"` instead of `checkEmptyVar $1 "folder to be copied"`

Comment: Run `command -V checkFolders` in the shell you are running this from and I expect you'll see something like `checkFolders() { checkEmptyVar "folder to be copied" }`

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Correct as far as it goes but not the problem here.

Comment: `$0` is not the first argument to the function; it would be name of the current script.

Comment: Hmm. Tempted to report a missing feature to http://shellcheck.net/ since it doesn't currently detect functions used prior to their definitions. (Granted, not all cases are necessarily errors -- the intent could be to use an external command pre-definition and shadow it later -- but it certainly warrants a warning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have numerous problems:

1. `$0` is not the first argument to a function; `$1` is. `$0` is the name of the current script.
2. You must quote parameter expansions to prevent them from being split into multiple words on embedded whitespace.
3. Functions must be defined before they are used.

The correct script is

```
#!/bin/bash


checkFolders() {
    checkEmptyVar "$1" "folder to be copied"
}

checkEmptyVar() {
    [[ $(isNotEmpty "$1") = false ]] && echo "Specify a path for $2" && exit
    echo "post exit"
}

checkFolders "first folder"
```

Further, it would be better to have `isNotEmpty` return a non-zero value instead of outputting the string `false`, so that you could write

```
checkEmptyVar () {
    if isNotEmpty "$1"; then
        echo "Specify a path for $2" >&2   # Use standard error, not standard output
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "post exit"
}
```

(I suspect you could replace `isNotEmpty` with `[[ -n $1 ]]` anyway.)

Comment: Thanks. THe thing is if I call `result=$(checkEmptyVar "value")`, my variable $result is empty despite the `exit 1` in the condition block. How can I do to return 1 into `var`? I also try with `return 1` but ny variable remains empty.

Comment: `checkEmptyVar "value"; result=$?`. However, you rarely need to save the return value of a command.

Answer (score 1):

This script isn't doing what you think it is. Your function definitions are happening too late.

When you call `checkFolders` on the first line you are calling a version of that function from the pre-existing environment and not the one defined later in that script.

If you run `command -V checkFolders` from the shell you are running this script from I expect you'll get output somewhat like:

```
checkFolders is a function
checkFolder ()
{
    checkEmptyVar "folder to be copied"
}
```

though anything is possible there.

You should also *always* quote variables when you use them to prevent the shell from word-splitting their contents.

Without doing that when you call `checkFolders "first folder"` that ends up calling `checkFolders first folder "folder to be copied"` which isn't what you want at all.

Invert the order of your functions and calls and fix your variable quoting and you should see what you expect.